# Change props value and Child component break on start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my render on CountryTabSequence component I have this error :

> src/components/CountryTabSequence.js:13:22,
>   Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Because the props value is an empty array when my page is loaded... How can I fix it and to rerender my component when my props is set ?

I tried with this fix in my Child component, but it's doesn't work :

```
if(sequence) {
    myForeach...
}
```

**PARENT : SequenceEdit.js**

```
class SequenceEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.props.getOneSequence(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CountryTabSequence sequence={this.props.currentSequence}/>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currentSequence: state.currentSequence
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    ...bindActionCreators({
        getOneSequence
    }, dispatch)
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SequenceEdit));
```

**CHILD : CountryTabSequence.js**

```
const renderCountryTabSequence = (sequence) => {
    let countryPreview = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">';

    if(sequence) {
        sequence.buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
            countryPreview += `<li class="nav-item">${bucket.country.code}</li>`;
        });
    }

    countryPreview += '</ul>';

    return countryPreview;
};

const CountryTabSequence = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: renderCountryTabSequence(props.sequence)}}></div>
    );
};

export default CountryTabSequence;
```

Comment: Why not also check if buckets are set in the sequence array before you try to forEach on it? `if (sequence && sequence.buckets) {`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check props (on all cases you got array - empty or not):

```
onst renderCountryTabSequence = (sequence) => {
    let countryPreview = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">';
    const { buckets = []} = sequence || {};
    if(Array.isArray(buckets)) {
        sequence.buckets.forEach((bucket) => {
            countryPreview += `<li class="nav-item">${bucket.country.code}</li>`;
        });
    }

    countryPreview += '</ul>';

    return countryPreview;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the empty condition of sequence (the required prop) in your child component.

```
const renderCountryTabSequence = (sequence) => {

  if (!sequence) {
    return <div>Loading ... ( or any loader component )  </div>
  }

  const htmlToReturn = (
    <ul className="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      {sequence.buckets.map(aBucket => (
        <li
          key={aBucket.country.code}
          className="nav-item">
          {aBucket.country.code}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )

  return htmlToReturn;
};
```

Comment: you don't need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for that, would be better to rewrite it to JSX

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the props and assign it a default value like this:

```
const CountryTabSequence = ({ sequence = [] }) => {
        return (
            <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: renderCountryTabSequence(sequence)}}></div>
        );
    };
```

or you can use defaultProps to assign a default value to the props as follows:

```
CountryTabSequence.defaultProps = {
   sequence: [],
}
```

I would also advice some kind of loading flag to show the user that the data is still being fetch or something like that so that it isn't a bad user experience.